# Issue with jQuery lightbox image position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gallery, image-gallery

I have written a custom modal window image gallery/lightbox and am having some issues with image positioning. Basically everything is fine when you select an image and click through sequentially, but if you exit the image and then reopen the same image the position is off to the right. I have no idea what could be the issue. I have the < img > positioned absolute and the container relative. I have set the CSS for the image to left: 50%; and top: 50%; and then use JS to calculate a negative left and top margin. Anyone have any idea as to why the position would change when reopening the image? Jsfiddle linked below. Thanks in advance!!

CSS:

```
#photoViewer {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
#photoViewer img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   max-height: 70vh; 
}
```

JS for margins:

```
$img.css({
    marginLeft: -$img.width() / 2,
    marginTop: -$img.height() / 2
})
```

and for the size of container div:

```
function adjustSize() {
var $width = $current.width();
var $height = $current.height();
$frame.css({
    width: $width,
    height: $height
});
```

}

(I got a lot of this code from Jon Duckett's "Javascript & jQuery" book but have tweaked it and combined several different elements/ideas).

Link to jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jessereitz1/6nxg21a3/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with your below function -

```
function adjustSize() {
  var $width = $current.width();
  var $height = $current.height();
  console.log($width,$height);  /*Debug in console*/
  $frame.css({
    width: $width,
    height: $height
  });
}
```

On first click above function return `width:200` and `height:133`

On second click above function return `width:0` and `height:0`

> This is the reason for that kinds of issue.

Another problem with `$cache = {}`, It's `cache[src].$img` Object not getting `width` and `height` property for the cache image.

```
function changeImg(index) {
  var $img;
  var src = $thumbnails[activeIndex].href;
  request = src;

  /*if(cache.hasOwnProperty(src)){
    if(cache[src].isLoading === false) {
        $frame.append(cache[src].$img);
        crossfade(cache[src].$img);
    }
  }else*/{
    $img = $('<img/>');
    cache[src] = {
        $img: $img,
        isLoading: true
    };

    $img.on('load', function() {
        $img.hide();
        $frame.removeClass('isLoading').append($img);
        cache[src].isLoading = false;
        if (request === src) {
            crossfade($img);
        }
    });

    $frame.addClass('isLoading');

    $img.attr({
        'src': src,
        'alt': $thumbnails[activeIndex].title || ''
    });
  }
}
```

Without checking cache, It provide proper result.

Comment: I did notice that too but I can't figure out why it's doing that. I placed the call for the function in the crossFade() function so it should be called every time a new image is shown. Do you have any idea why that could be? I tried moving around the function call but nothing seems to make it resize itself again...

Comment: Ok, Checking ... @JesseReitz

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you so much @SumonSarker!!